# Property Projection cannot be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I am trying to create a table using serverless framework and even though I have specified Projection for the GSI, serverless is complaining that property `Projection` cannot be empty.
Am I getting the syntax wrong?
If I remove the GSI section it works pretty fine.

```yaml
Table1: 
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties: 
    AttributeDefinitions: 
    - AttributeName: "uid"
      AttributeType: "S"
    - AttributeName: "bid"
      AttributeType: "S"
    KeySchema: 
    - AttributeName: "uid"
      KeyType: "HASH"
    - AttributeName: "bid"
      KeyType: "RANGE"
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: "bid-uid-index"
    - KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: "bid"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      - AttributeName: "uid"
        KeyType: "RANGE"
    - Projection: 
      - ProjectionType: "ALL"
    - ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    ProvisionedThroughput: 
      ReadCapacityUnits: 1
      WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    TableName: "Table1"
```

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, my syntax was wrong

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
- IndexName: "bid-uid-index"
    KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: "bid"
    KeyType: "HASH"
    - AttributeName: "uid"
    KeyType: "RANGE"
    Projection: 
    ProjectionType: "ALL"
    ProvisionedThroughput:
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
```

Changin it to above fixed the errors...